# Files in ItemGroup not detected by AfterBuild Target

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

**What the question should have been:**

Here is the content of my `ModuleCompilation.targets` file :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ConfigFilesToMove Include="bin\$(Configuration)\*.config"/>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="Message for AfterBuild" />
    <Move SourceFiles="@(ConfigFilesToMove)" DestinationFolder="bin\$(Configuration)\Configuration\" />
</Target>
```

The Message is written to the console but the files are not moved, how come ?

**Original question (you can ignore):**

I have included an Import in my csproj file to import a task from another file :

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="..\ModuleCompilation.targets" />
```

Now, here is the content of my ModuleCompilation.targets file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="AfterBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <BaseFiles Include="bin\$(Configuration)\Libraries\ModuleBase*"/>
        <ConfigFilesToMove Include="bin\$(Configuration)\*.config"/>
        <OtherFilesToMove Include="bin\$(Configuration)\*" Exclude="bin\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <Message Text="AfterBuild" />
        <Move SourceFiles="@(ConfigFilesToMove)" DestinationFolder="bin\$(Configuration)\Configuration\" />
        <Move SourceFiles="@(OtherFilesToMove)" DestinationFolder="bin\$(Configuration)\Libraries\" />
        <Message Text="bin\$(Configuration)\Libraries\ModuleBase*" />
        <Delete Files="@(BaseFiles)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

When I build or rebuild, I do have the "AfterBuild" message in my console, and the files are all indeed generated, but they haven't moved from the Debug folder to where I want them to be.

If I rebuild my projet, the files are moved, I guess because there already were present, but I want to files to be generated and then to be moved, I don't want to have them to be already present !

I must be missing something really obvious, can you help me please ?

Edit:

Ok so I've made some tests and this works :

```
<ConfigFilesToMove Include="bin\Debug\App.config"/>
```

While this doesn't:

```
<ConfigFilesToMove Include="bin\Debug\*.config"/>
```

Does anyone knowns why ?

Edit 2:
This is really weird, here is my code :

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Files Include="$(OutputPath)*.config"/>

        <Pouet Include="bin\Debug\*.dll"/>
      </ItemGroup>

      <Target Name="AfterBuild">
            <Message Text="@(Pouet)" />
            <Message Text="pouetss" Condition="Exists(@(Pouet))"/>
            <Message Text="nooo" Condition="!Exists(@(Pouet))"/>
            <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)Configuration\" />
            <Copy SourceFiles="@(Pouet)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)Configuration\" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Here is what the log from MSBuild says :

```
1>Target "AfterBuild: (TargetId:75)" in file "C:\Tests\ModuleTest\Modules\ModuleCompilation.targets" from project         "C:\Tests\ModuleTest\Modules\FirstModule\FirstModule.csproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
1>Task "Message" (TaskId:47)
1>Done executing task "Message". (TaskId:47)
1>Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; (Exists(@(Pouet))) was evaluated as (Exists()).
1>Task "Message" (TaskId:48)
1>  Task Parameter:Text=nooo (TaskId:48)
1>  nooo (TaskId:48)
1>Done executing task "Message". (TaskId:48)
1>Task "MakeDir" (TaskId:49)
1>  Task Parameter:Directories=bin\Debug\Configuration\ (TaskId:49)
1>  Creating directory "bin\Debug\Configuration\". (TaskId:49)
1>Done executing task "MakeDir". (TaskId:49)
1>Task "Copy" (TaskId:50)
1>  Task Parameter:DestinationFolder=bin\Debug\Configuration\ (TaskId:50)
1>Done executing task "Copy". (TaskId:50)
1>Done building target "AfterBuild" in project "FirstModule.csproj".: (TargetId:75)
```

So MSBuild ignores every value that contains a wildcard ?

Comment: Probably due to evaluation order; did you try putting the ItemGroup inside the target, so it's evaluated when the target runs (and when the files exist already)?

Comment: Thank you for you answer @stijn. Thanks to your comment, I've found this link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/10/04/476725.aspx which says that I should use a CreateItem task inside a Target because item groups outside of a Target are resolved before the targets are run. Also, the MSDN says that the CreateItem task is deprecated and that I should instead place an item group in a Target element (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2y3e43x), so I'm guessing you are right. I will update my post as soon asI have the chance to try our theory.

Answer (score 7):

**Problem :**

ItemGroup created outside of a Target are resolved before any Target is run, so you can't target files that a Target will create

**Solution :**

I changed my code to :

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ConfigFilesToMove Include="bin\$(Configuration)\*.config"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Message for AfterBuild" />
    <Move SourceFiles="@(ConfigFilesToMove)" DestinationFolder="bin\$(Configuration)\Configuration\" />
</Target>
```

And now my files are detected because the ItemGroup is resolved after the files are created.